# committedValuesForKeys returns an empty dictionary on NSManaged object subclass

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm using a NSManaged object subclass that was generated by the core data GUI tool in XCode.

NSLog'ing the object reveals that it's properly instantiated and holding values... But if I try to use something like this:

```
[generatedSubClass committedValuesForKeys:nil]
```

I get back an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs state that `committedValuesForKeys`

> Returns a dictionary of the last fetched or saved values of the receiver for the properties specified by the given keys.

It follows that the object you are messaging is not the last fetched or saved.

Also, note that `committedValuesForKeys` is an instance method, not a class method.

Thus, not <strike>`[managedObjectSubclass committedValuesForKeys:nil]`</strike>
but `[aManagedObject committedValuesForKeys:nil]`

Comment: Is there an easy way of getting the keys and values then? Or do I have to resport to class_copyPropertyList()?

Comment: @LukeTheObscure, Core Data provides much better introspection than that-- try looking up the object's `NSEntityDescription` via the `entity` attribute.

Comment: I ended up using this category, but beware that it will give you ALL properties, not just the interesting CoreData ones.  https://gist.github.com/andrewsardone/553633

Comment: You definitely should have used Core Data standard introspection with `NSEntityDescription`…